# TeamCity can't connect to TFS

Tags: tfs, teamcity

I'm trying to set up a TFS VCS root in TeamCity and I'm getting `TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://tfsserver.com:8080/tfs`.  I know that the account that I'm using has access to the TFS server because it's the same one I use for Visual Studio and it works fine.

I checked the logs and they say that the request is returning a 500 error.  For not authorized I would have expected a 401.  Has anybody seen something like this before?

Comment: "The account I'm using", are you talking about the AD account you log into TeamCity with or the one you're running the server service under or the one you're running the build agent service under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do much with Team City but I would expect that it wants a URL to either a Collection or Team Project (which is not what the URL in your question is).

http://tfsserver.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection

or

http://tfsserver.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject